# Ruby: How to print ®

Tags: ruby, unicode

1. Save rb file with ASCII, ® can't be right displayed
2. Save rb file with Unicode, it would cause error
   Invalid char `\357' in expression
   Invalid char`\273' in expression
   Invalid char `\277' in expression

Comment: 1. Where do you want to print it? Not all places can display it. 2. Which ruby version?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try Array#pack.

```
puts [174].pack('U*')
```

That won't require any non-ASCII characters in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the source encoding:

```
# coding: utf-8
p "®"
```

(just add the `# coding: utf-8` line in your file to declare its encoding to utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

If you're displaying this in a web browser, use the `&reg;` or `&#174;` HTML entities. The browser should interpret them as the correct character.